# Install php_mysql extension on windows/xampp PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have to work on legacy project which runs on `php_mysql`. My local environment is windows/xampp with PHP version 7.

I have downloaded `php_mysql.dll` from somewhere and added it to my php extension path `c:/xampp/php/ext` and added the line `extension=php_mysql.dll` to php.ini file. But still `extension_loaded("mysql")` returns false.

I ran php on command line and I get the following error:

> `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.`

I have:

1. restarted the apache everytime I made a change
2. tried adding the full path to php.ini

How can I install this extension?

Comment: I suggest you install PHP v5. Any production environment you deploy this code to will not be running v7. Try running it in Docker ~ https://hub.docker.com/r/nimmis/apache-php5/

Comment: php_mysql is not supported in php7 anymore, if you need to work with it you need to install xammp for php5 or wamp which comes with both versions and you can change according to your need